# reading "--plat-name" argument in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools

The setuptools `bdist_wheel`/`bdist_egg` commands have a `--plat-name` argument that allows for overriding the host platform name.  This value gets tacked onto the name of the resulting file, e.g., `mypackage-1.2.3-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`.

How can I read this value in `setup.py`?  Note I'm *not* asking for the host platform the script is running on, e.g., `platform.system()`.  I want the platform name that setuptools is using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bdist_egg` (and only it; `bdist_wheel` just runs `bdist_egg`) `--plat-name` argument is stored in `self.plat_name`. So you can override `bdist_egg` with your custom class and use `self.plat_name`:

```
from setuptools.command.bdist_egg import bdist_egg as _bdist_egg
from setuptools import setup

class bdist_egg(_bdist_egg):
    def run(self):
        # Use self.plat_name before building an egg…
        _bdist_egg.run(self)
        # …or after

setup(
    …
    cmdclass={
        'bdist_egg': bdist_egg,
    },
    …
)
```

Comment: This may have been true in the past, but `bdist_wheel` does not (as of `0.32.3`) invoke `bdist_egg`.